# Android java - how to make string source of html

Tags: java, android

how to tell engine string containing html. i am using it for print command.

its prints but html code not content.

here is code

```
                String m="<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN'><html><body><h1>Hello</h1><br><h2>new line</h2></body></html>";
                cmd[2] &= 0xEF;
                mService.write(cmd);           
                mService.sendMessage(m, "GBK");
```

this is much needed please help.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this if you want in android:

```
 String m="<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN'><html><body><h1>Hello</h1><br><h2>new line</h2></body></html>";
            cmd[2] &= 0xEF;
            mService.write(cmd);           
            mService.sendMessage(Html.fromHtml(m), "GBK");
```

Comment: error : The method sendMessage(String, String) in the type BluetoothService is not applicable for the arguments (Spanned, String)

Comment: sorry then i dont know how to send Html text to printer.

Comment: do u know how to get WebView source code and store into string variable.

Comment: sorry i dont know.. :(